# Can a character cast Bless on themselves?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting

Last night during a game session, one of the players cast Bless, and requested to target himself as well as 2 party members. On review of the PHB for spell casting and ranges, it was not specified if the caster counts as a valid target for a non-self spell. It **did** mention cone and line spells that originated from the caster (as in targeting a point at the casters location and emanating out from there), but made no such distinction for ranged spells.

I ruled that the caster was not a valid target, as the range was not self, but now I'm not so sure.

**Is the caster of a ranged spell such as Bless considered a valid target (creature in range)?**

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Yes, the caster can include themselves in most spells that target creatures. From the PHB's Spellcasting chapter, the section on Targets (page 204):

> **Targeting Yourself**
>
> If a spell targets a creature of your choice, you can
> choose yourself, unless the creature must be hostile or
> specifically a creature other than you. If you are in the
> area of effect of a spell you cast, you can target yourself.

In the case of *Bless* specifically, it targets creatures of your choice, exactly as described in the above rule:

> You bless up to three creatures of your choice within
> range.

The range is 30 feet, and you are always within 30 feet of yourself, so you can always choose to have *Bless* affect you.

Comment: "_you can always choose to have_ Bless _affect you_", unless for whatever reason you're casting through another source, and you're not in range.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this clarification. Reading through the spells I was confused about this because non-cleric spells like Pass Without A Trace and Etherealness explicitly state "(including you)" while the cleric spells Aid, Bless, Prayer of Healing, etc. do not.