# How does additional damage work with the Hand Mortar's explosive property?

Tags: dnd-5e, gunslinger

So I am building a gunslinger, and see a possible very high risk, but very high reward tactic for large groups.

Say I have a hand mortar, and fire it into a creature surrounded by at least 2 others. The hand mortar has the explosive property

> **Explosive.** Upon a hit, everything within 5 ft  of the target must make
> a Dexterity saving throw (DC equal to 8 + your  proficiency bonus +
> your Dexterity modifier) or suffer 1d8 fire damage.  If the weapon
> misses, the ammunition fails to detonate, or bounces away  harmlessly
> before doing so.

Now say I choose to spend 2 grit points on the Violent Shot trick shot.

> When you make a firearm attack against a  creature, you can expend one
> or more grit points to enhance the  volatility of the attack. For each
> grit point expended, the attack gains  a +2 to the firearm’s misfire
> score. If the attack hits, you can roll  one additional weapon damage
> die per grit point spent when determining  the damage.

Does this mean that if I hit and  do not misfire (*roll above a 7, and above the main target's AC*) I deal **6d8 + DEX fire damage** to the main target AND a potential **3d8 fire damage** to the creature around the target, or does the "splash damage" not count as weapon damage?

This is entirely based on the [DnD beyond Gunslinger subclass](https://www.dndbeyond.com/subclasses/gunslinger) definition.

Comment: Highly related (dupe?): [If an attack causes additional damage after a saving throw, is it counted as a separate source of damage for the purpose of failed death saves?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/152419)

Comment: Related as well: "[Is Ice Knife's explosion damage affected by rolling a critical?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/91895)" and "[Does the Assassin rogue’s Death Strike feature double the damage from a poison that requires a saving throw?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/162490)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Violent Shot grants *a* *weapon die*

Per your *Violent Shot* citation (emphasis mine),

> When you make a firearm attack against a creature, you can expend one or more grit points to enhance the volatility of the attack. For each grit point expended, the attack gains a +2 to the firearm’s misfire score. If the attack hits, you can roll **one** additional **weapon damage die** per grit point spent when determining the damage.

Tackling these in reverse emphasis order, *Violent Shot* adds to your weapon damage.  The Hand Mortar does 2d8 + Dex fire damage and has the Explosive property, which deals additional fire damage to nearby enemies. To minimize semantic arguments, note that the target hit by the weapon *does not* take this additional damage*. It follows that the Explosive property does not confer weapon damage and therefore does not get amplified by *Violent Shot*.  This is supported by a similar answer on a related question [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/127440/what-are-weapon-damage-dice).

The other word I've bolded is "one", though that's reinforced by the non-plural "weapon damage **die**".  Your mortar's weapon damage **dice** are 2d8, but its **die** is a d8. As such, Violent Shot would add 1d8 per grit point spent.  With two points, your total is 4d8 + Dex to your target, plus 1d8 to targets within 5 feet

*See this [related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103385/does-the-target-of-lightning-arrow-take-the-secondary-damage-too) and its accepted answer featuring a ruling by Jeremy Crawford, the Lead Rules Designer for this edition

Comment: "note that the target hit by the weapon does not take this additional damage." could you support this claim? We have a [question about such phrases](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/157308) and other related questions as well such as: "[Can a character cast Bless on themselves?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/99615)" and "[Does the target of Lightning Arrow take the secondary damage too?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/103385)" I may ask about this as its own question actually...

Comment: Also note that the "Sage Advice" ruling in the question you've linked is not the official Sage Advice Compendium but nothing more than a tweet. It is not an official ruling. That said, I definitely think there's enough wiggle room and ambiguity for a GM to rule either way in terms of whether or not the initial target takes damage twice.